# RSS security for admin data

Tags: magento

Magento has a built in frontend rss feed for customer orders via /rss/sales/orders that is blocked via page auth which seems open to brute force attacks?

Also if I was to use the same function for access via frontend to fetch other system data ( customers list etc)

Is this good practice to have frontend single login access for this output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest potentially blocking access to the RSS. It has recently been under heavy attack across a multitude of Magento stores.

It is open to Brute Force attacks yes and has been known to fail & allow access.

```
location ~* /rss/order/new {
return 403;
}
location ~* /rss/catalog/notifystock {
return 403;
}
location ~* /rss/catalog/review {
return 403;
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Thank to a colleague for picking this up.